# Mclust: Data frame order affects solution

Tags: r, clustering, model-based-clustering

I've come across some behavior in `mclust::Mclust` that I would not have expected, which is that the order of variables in the data passed to `Mclust` affects the solution it comes up with.

In the example below, the first ordering of the variables produces 2 profiles, and the second produces 6. However, calling either of these orders *does* produce a stable solution (e.g., the first call to `Mclust` will always produce 2 profiles).

```
> testData <- read.file(f = "http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/chess.dat")

> summary(Mclust(subset(testData, select = c(X1, X3, X5, X7, X9, X11))))
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust EEV (ellipsoidal, equal volume and shape) model with 2 components:

 log.likelihood    n df      BIC      ICL
       3547.068 3195 49 6698.738 6692.126

Clustering table:
   1    2 
2759  436 


> summary(Mclust(subset(testData, select = c(X11, X9, X1, X3, X5, X7))))
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust EEV (ellipsoidal, equal volume and shape) model with 6 components:

 log.likelihood    n  df      BIC      ICL
       18473.94 3195 137 35842.37 35834.51

Clustering table:
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
431 932 210 881 524 217
```

My suspicion is that the initialization step (that the documentation suggests is a hierarchical clustering procedure) is affected by the order of variable passed, but I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to overcome this.

**Update:** It appears that there is something to my suspicion that the initialization step is involved in this behavior. If I load the same dataset as above, but instead pass `Mclust` an `hcPairs` list to its `initialization` argument that's based on an `EII` model, I get stable results across variable orders:

```
> testData <- read.file(f = "http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/chess.dat")

> hc <- hc(subset(testData, select = c(X1, X3, X5, X7, X9, X11)), modelName = "EII")
> summary(Mclust(subset(testData, select = c(X1, X3, X5, X7, X9, X11)), initialization=list(hcPairs = hc)))
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust VEV (ellipsoidal, equal shape) model with 2 components:

 log.likelihood    n df      BIC      ICL
       3391.936 3195 50 6380.405 6380.254

Clustering table:
   1    2 
1386 1809 
> summary(Mclust(subset(testData, select = c(X11, X9, X1, X3, X5, X7)), initialization=list(hcPairs = hc)))
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust VEV (ellipsoidal, equal shape) model with 2 components:

 log.likelihood    n df      BIC      ICL
       3391.936 3195 50 6380.405 6380.254

Clustering table:
   1    2 
1386 1809
```

Interestingly, this doesn't match either of the first two cluster/profile solutions above (the *n*s for the two-profile solution above don't match). I also don't have a clear understanding of why an `EII` model in the `hc` step produces these effects, I simply tried all possible models in the `hc` step and `EII` was the only one that produced these stable solutions.

Can anyone confirm that this is a sound way to go about this type of profile analysis, or offer an alternate solution?

Comment: Interesting. The second result is also very different in quality. Have you verified it is the initialization? How do results compare to other EM results such as with ELKI's EM? What if you fix the cluster number to 2/6?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I updated the question above to include more information on the initialization step. If I fix the number of factors at 2 in my original example, the first analysis (X1, X3, X5...) produces the same solution. The second analysis (X11, X9, X1...) produces a 2-profile solution, but it doesn't match the first analysis.

Comment: So, does hc yield different results then?

Comment: In comparing the `hc` call that mClust would normally do that resulted in different output, the `hc` output seems the same:
hc1 <- hc(subset(testData, select = c(X1, X3, X5, X7, X9, X11)))
hc2 <- hc(subset(testData, select = c(X11, X9, X1, X3, X5, X7)))
hc1 %in% hc2

Comment: Have you tried setting a seed?

Answer (score 1):

You may try SVD transformation described in *Scrucca and Raftery (2015)*.
In this paper they pointed out the order of variables of your input data may affect your initial output of hc algorithm.

Mclust package does offer such options. Just like

```
mod <- Mclust(X, initialization = list(hcPairs = hc(X, use = “SVD”)))
```